# sudo update-grub not working: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2'

Tags: grub2

i'm getting this error when entering "sudo update-grub" on terminal (and it also affects with "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" when about to install a linux-image-* package)

```
guest@athlon-6t:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2'.
No path or device is specified.
Usage: grub-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE]
Try 'grub-probe --help' or 'grub-probe --usage' for more information.
guest@athlon-6t:~$
```

how can we get a better report of what is happening, and get this fixed? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

(I guess that `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` fixed it? :O )

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had almost the same problem. On update-grub I got the error message: "...failed to get canonical path of /boot/grub/fonts/UbuntuMono16.pf2" and update-grub would fail.

After some digging around, I found: In "/etc/default/grub.d/" I had a file named "60_mint-theme.cfg" with a line: 'GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub/fonts/UbuntuMono16.pf2"'. However, my file in "/boot/grub/fonts/Ubuntu" was named "unicode.pf2". Reason: I had just performed a "boot-repair" routine. Obviously boot-repair had put the file "unicode.pf2" into the /boot/grub/fonts/Ubuntu" folder, which was now in conflict with the configuration that Linux Mint had established during the original installation.

When I replaced the problematic line in "60_mint-theme.cfg", 'GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub/fonts/UbuntuMono16.pf2", with 'GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2"' the update worked fine and I was saved from having to do a re-install in my desparation.

Comment: This is very hard to follow

Comment: Short version: a) compare content of "/etc/default/grub.d/60_mint-theme.cfg" with file in "/boot/grub/fonts/Ubuntu". b) Repair by adusting the former. - Maybe one can just delete the content in "/etc/default/grub.d/60_mint-theme.cfg" or delete the whole file, but I did not try that.